# How can I make a unit test that tests my Spring/OSGi configuration?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have a bundle-context-osgi.xml file that lists services my project takes and services it publishes.  I also have a bundle-context.xml that defines the beans defined in my application.  How can I write a unit test that ensures that everything is wired correctly and I can product the services that my application is supposed to provide when it is on the server?

Note: it might be wrong to call this a "unit test" but I think the idea is clear.

Answer (score 2):

For OSGi Integration Tests I usually use Pax Exam. It will start a osgi container publish all configured bundles and will create a tiny-bundle from the testsources to be deployed as a OSGi bundle. 
With it you are able to access all registered services even by @Inject means. 
Best to take a look at the [Pax Exam documentation](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM4/Pax+Exam).

In short you create a new integration test module, where you configure your dependencies in the Test case:

```
@RunWith(PaxExam.class)
@ExamReactorStrategy(PerMethod.class)
public class MyTest {

@Inject
protected BundleContext bundleContext;

@Inject 
MyService service;

...

@Configuration
public Option[] configure() {
    return options(
            workingDirectory("target/paxexam/"),
            cleanCaches(true),
            junitBundles(),
            mavenBundle().groupId("my.group.id")
                    .artifactId("my-artifact")
                    .version("1.0.0")
    ...
          );
    }

    ...

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
         assertNotNull(service);
    }
}
```